# cookies redirect loop not working

Tags: php, session, cookies, mysqli, error-handling

Soo i dont know what else to do, its causing soo much problems, so this is the code, i want him to stay logged on but this is not working as intended, i want him if he is logged in and goes to index page to redirect him to welcome.php but its not working as it should, sometime it says This webpage has redirect loop

this is index.php

```
<?php 

    error_reporting(0);

    session_start();


    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","samp");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['login_button']))
    {

        $userName = $_POST['username']; 
        $userPass = $_POST['password']; 

        $hashedPass = hash('whirlpool', $userPass);
        $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'";

        $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if($row)
        {
            $session = md5($userName.$hashedPass);
            mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Igraci SET session = '$session' WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'");
            setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time()+3600*24);
            setcookie("authorization","ok");
            header( "Location:welcome.php");
            echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']). ' <a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
        }
        else
        {
            header("location: index.php?err=1");
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['logout']))
    {
        setcookie("username", "", time()-60);
        setcookie("authorization", "no" );
        header( "Location:index.php");
        exit(); # stop executing here
    }


    if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "ok") {
        header ("Location:welcome.php");
        exit();
    }
    else if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "no")
    {
        header ("Location:welcome.php");
        exit();

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roleplay Factory User Control Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome, please login to your account.</h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" required placeholder = "Username" name="username">
    <input type="password" required placeholder = "Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
</form> 

<div class="footer">
<p>roleplay factory &copy; 2016 all rights reserved</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is welcome.php

```
<?php 
    $auth = $_COOKIE['authorization'];
    header ("Cache-Control:no-cache");
    if(!$auth == "ok") {
        header ("Location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>

<html>
<head> <title>Logged In</title> </head>
<body>
    <p>Successful log-in.</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**THE PROBLEM:**

When you logout you first delete the cookie, but then you set it as `no`. Note that if you have `$_COOKIE['authorization']=='no'` you are going to fall in the loop because of:

```
if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "ok") {
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();
}
else if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "no")
{
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();
}
```

So, as you said:

> sometime it says This webpage has redirect loop

I guess the first time (no cookie is set) you can see the index because it ignore `$_COOKIE['authorization'] == "ok"` and `$_COOKIE['authorization'] == "no"`. Then when you login and logout, you fall in the loop because now `$_COOKIE['authorization'] == "no"` is `true`.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Just delete the cookie, don't set it as `"no"` (delete or comment `setcookie("authorization", "no" );`).

**BONUS:**

Delete

```
else if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "no")
{
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();

}
```

You don't need it any more and this ony can cause problems.

Comment: So something like this:

I've tested it and i think it works, what do you think did i make it to easy to sql inject and what can i do to preveent it ?

http://i.imgur.com/Hu5cTp7.jpg

Comment: I think in fact it is easy to inject MySQL code the way the page is programed, @trincot's answer explain how to solve this problem and some others, check it out. Also,

Comment: [Sent the previous comment by error]: 

I think in fact it is easy to inject MySQL code the way the page is programmed, @trincot's answer explain how to solve this problem and some others,  take a look. 

Also, consider to use another way to store the cookie. User can change cookie's content from his end, so, if I know your user name, I can make the system think I'm logged with your user. [Here are some ideas](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence).

If my first answer solved the problem, consider to upvote and mark as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: i dont think that would be possible if i hash password and store it as a cookie, am i right ?

Comment: Password is a sensitive infomation, maybe you can hash a combination of user ID, username and some random generated string for the user when he/she  register an account (that way you can be sure all users has unique cookie string and nobody knows how his/her own token is generated).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

### 1. Bad redirection in index.php

In this piece of code you redirect the user to *welcome.php* even when the user is not authorised:

```
if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "ok") {
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();
}
else if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "no")
{
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();
}
```

You don't want that. Instead you'll want to show the *index.php* page or redirect to some *unauth.php* (if you have something like that). But if you want to leave an unauthorised user on the *index.php* so they can relog, then just leave out the `else` part:

```
if($_COOKIE['authorization'] == "ok") {
    header ("Location:welcome.php");
    exit();
}
```

### 2. Bad condition in welcome.php

```
if(!$auth == "ok") {
```

This condition will always fail, even when `$auth == "ok"`. That is because the `!` operator applies only to `$auth` not to the equality.

In fact, because of this bug, your first problem was not as bad as it could have been, because if this condition had been written as it should, you would always have a redirection loop once the user was logged on!

Instead write:

```
if($auth !== "ok") {
```

### 3. Generating output when redirecting

You should never combine `echo` or `print` with `header(location. ...)`. Whichever comes first will make the other statement fail.

Also, if you do not `exit` after a `header` statement, you risk to continue to execute other code which is not appropriate.

So this piece of code:

```
        ...
        header( "Location:welcome.php");
        echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']). ' <a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: index.php?err=1");
    }
```

... has these types of problems. As there is no `exit` the code below it is also executed, which also has `header` statements! This will certainly lead to undesired behaviour.

You should remove the `echo`, and add an `exit` right after each of the `header` statements:

```
        ...
        header( "Location:welcome.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: index.php?err=1");
        exit();
    }
```

### 4. SQL Injection Vulnerability

As you build your SQL query string from data that is coming via the request (`$_POST`), your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Use prepared statements instead. This is how you could change your code to prevent SQL injection:

```
// Use placeholders where you want to insert user-supplied data:
$query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = ? AND Lozinka = ?";
// Let the DB engine compile this statement:
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
// Tell DB engine what the parameters are (this is safe):
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $userName, $hashedPass);
// Execute the query with these parameter values:
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
// Fetch the result object:
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```